# Manually setting the maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFee works. Same values but dynamically set fail. How come?

Tags: ether, ethers.js, javascript

Trying to do a simple transfer of Eth in Ethers js. When manually setting the maxFeePerGas and the maxPriorityFeePerGas, the transaction goes through. Yet when I use feeData from wallet.getFeeData(), even if the values are lower than the manual setting, the Tx fails, citing "insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost".

This test was repeated a number of times, with the same result. What do you think is going on? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
async transfer(destinationAddress: string, amountInWei: ethers.BigNumberish) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`transferring ${amountInWei} wei to ${destinationAddress} over ${this.network.toString()}`)
    const privateKey = await this.getSecretKey('wallet-private-key')
    const config = await this.getConfig()
    const alchemy = new Alchemy(config)
    const wallet = new Wallet(privateKey, alchemy)
    const chainId = (await alchemy.core.getNetwork()).chainId
    const nonce = await alchemy.core.getTransactionCount(wallet.address, 'latest')

    const gasLimit = await wallet.estimateGas({
      to: destinationAddress,
      value: amountInWei,
    })

    const feeData = await wallet.getFeeData()

    // const maxPriorityFeePerGas = feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas ?? Utils.parseUnits('15', 'gwei')
    const maxPriorityFeePerGas = Utils.parseUnits('15', 'gwei')
    // const maxFeePerGas = feeData.maxFeePerGas ?? Utils.parseUnits('620', 'gwei')
    const maxFeePerGas = Utils.parseUnits('620', 'gwei')

    console.log(
      `Signing trx with - nonce-${nonce} gasLimit=${gasLimit} maxPriorityFeePerGas=${maxPriorityFeePerGas} default=${Utils.parseUnits('20', 'gwei')} maxFeePerGas=${maxFeePerGas}, default=${Utils.parseUnits('500', 'gwei')}`,
    )

    const rawTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction({
      to: destinationAddress,
      value: amountInWei,
      gasLimit,
      maxPriorityFeePerGas,
      maxFeePerGas,
      nonce,
      chainId,
      type: 2,
    })

    const tx = await alchemy.core.sendTransaction(rawTransaction)
    console.log('Sent transaction', tx) // eslint-disable-line
    const ret: Tx = {
      hash: tx.hash,
      from: tx.from,
      to: tx.to,
      timestamp: tx.timestamp,
      type: tx.type ?? undefined,
      value: tx.value.toString(),
    }
    return ret
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using values from `getFeeData()` to send transactions seems to be working fine.

I tried it and couldn't reproduce the error you're getting.

Here's the script to send a transaction using values from `getFeeData()` through Alchemy SDK:

```js
// Imports the Alchemy SDK
const { Alchemy, Network, Wallet, Utils } = require("alchemy-sdk");
const ethers = require('ethers');

// Configures the Alchemy SDK
const config = {
    apiKey: "demo", // Replace with your API key
    network: Network.ETH_GOERLI, // Replace with your network
};

// Creates an Alchemy object instance with the config to use for making requests
const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);


const PRIVATE_KEY = "your-private-key";

const main = async () => {

    let feeData = await alchemy.core.getFeeData()

    console.log(feeData)

    const wallet = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);

    const transaction = {
        to: "0xFd706f0A70074FB3A6c251C2d65B0433E2e902c8",
        value: Utils.parseEther("0.1"),
        gasLimit: "21000",
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
        maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas,
        nonce: await alchemy.core.getTransactionCount(wallet.getAddress()),
        type: 2,
        chainId: 5, // Corresponds to ETH_GOERLI
      };

    const rawTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
    const responseTx = await alchemy.transact.sendTransaction(rawTransaction)
    const result = await responseTx.wait();

    // Logging the response to the console
    console.log(result)

};

main();
```

Remember to replace the values for your API key, private key and network.